# Deleted symlink to /etc and now missing sudoers

Tags: sudo, macos

I messed up bad, **real bad**.

I accidentally deleted the symbolic link to my `/etc` directory. Now I can't create another one because I keep getting an error:

```
$ sudo ln -s /private/etc /etc
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Output of `ls -l /etc`:

```
$ ls -l /etc
ls: /etc: No such file or directory
```

My `/etc` was symlinked to `/private/etc` (sudoers is in there).

Answer (score 3):

1. Boot to Recovery Mode (cmd-R)
2. Open Terminal from the menubar Utilities > Terminal
3. Soft-link /private/etc to /etc **on your main Volume**:

   ```
   ln -s private/etc /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/etc
   ```

   Replace `Macintosh\ HD` with the name of your main volume (if your forgot it, just enter `df` or `ls /Volumes/` and check for its name! Don't forget to escape blanks with a backslash.)

Comment: It should use a relative link target: `ln -s private/etc /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/etc`

Comment: You are right...but the other solution works too - your solution creates the original link content (etc -> private/etc) though

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Without sudo you can not run commands as root without entering the root user's password.

If you do know the password of the root user then run

```
/usr/bin/su - root -c "ln -s /private/etc /etc"
```

and enter the password of the root user.

Comment: Using `su` has the same issue as `sudo`, it won't authorize because the command can't find `sudoers`.

Comment: The `su` command does not require `/etc/sudoers` (and the `sudo` in this command is unnecessary -- if you can run `su`, then you're already root and `sudo` is a no-op). If the you know the root password, this is probably the easiest solution, once you drop the `sudo`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that if you create a MacOS bootable installer (e.g., via [these instructions](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201372)) that you will have access to a terminal prompt.  This requires that:

- you have access to a second MacOS device (yours, a friend's, etc) on which you can create bootable media,
- a spare USB flash drive or other removable media, and
- sufficient knowledge to mount your hard drive manually from within the installer environment.

At that point, you should be able to replace the `/etc` symlink.

I don't have access to a MacOS device on which to test this right now, but I will in a couple of days. If I have the chance, I'll try to validate these instructions and update them if necessary.